# How to get emacs ctrl-d functionality back

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I was working with a colleague who is also emacs user and while he was working he might have tried to establish his preferred key bindings without me knowing. I am now back to using emacs on my machine and the ctrl-d key no longer does delete the character. How do I re-establish that functionality? I closed and re-opened my file but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: `C-h k` `d` to see what it is bound to, `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-d") #'delete-char)` would bind it in the global map.  But if that got rebound there is probably something in your init that should be removed

Comment: What @Rorschach said. And see what `C-d` does in different modes. Maybe some major or minor mode has rebound it.